# SQL: How to "select into outfile" the owner of current user?

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

If I run something like: mysql -e "select ... into outfile ...", it will create file with owner of "mysql:mysql" instead of current user. Then I have to do chown after, which is not convenient. Is there a way to do it better? Thanks.

Comment: That you find a working solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Unix, an option is to use the  `system` command ([4.5.1.2 mysql Commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-commands.html)).

```sh
$ mysql -e "select ... into outfile ...; system chown $USER:$USER ...;"
```

Evaluate the necessary permissions.

Comment: At least for me that does not work executed from `$USER` context: `chown: changing ownership of '/tmp/test.csv': Operation not permitted`

Comment: @membersound I am not using `chown` but trying to delete the file, I get the same error. I got around this by creating a subdir in `/tmp` and setting its permissions to 777. If the file is written in there it can be deleted, whereas the sticky bit in `/tmp` prevents that. Perhaps it works with `chown` too.